# What excel format i have file in?

Tags: excel

I got excel file with .XLS format, excel 2007 can open it, but throws a message that file is in another format then is an extension and if im sure to want open it.

I opened file in notepad and these are the first lines

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"      xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<meta name="ProgId" content="Excel.Sheet" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Excel 9" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
```

I tried save the file as another formats like .xml, .ods and so on, but i cant find the real format/extension name. Dont you know what it is ? It seems its fully compatible with excel.

Comment: This looks like an Excel file being saved as web-page. Try renaming it to `*.html` and opening in browser.

Comment: It can be opened in browser but the format is stray/broken. I tried create .xls file and save it as .html and the header is very similar but little different


<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta name="Excel Workbook Frameset">
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 12">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i found the format, its .XLHTML

And this C# Code told me

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

excelApp.Visible = false;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook eWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsFilePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

Console.WriteLine(eWorkbook.FileFormat.ToString());

Console.ReadLine();
```